# Lazy Loading with template engine's like velocity

Tags: java, lazy-loading, velocity, template-engine, freemarker

In an application we are using Velocity to merge placeholders in templates. So ${firstname} is merged to a users first name because we add it before merging in a VelocityContext Hashmap.

Code:

```
public static String evaluateTemplate(final VelocityContext context, final String template){
    try {
        velocityEngine.init();
        StringWriter writer = new StringWriter();
        velocityEngine.evaluate(context, writer, "", template);
        return writer.toString();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        ...
    }           
}
```

This is a very simple example and always adding first name, even if it isn't used in the template, to the VelocityContext isn't an expensive operation because user property fields (getters from a Hibernate entity) are most of the time needed when evaluating a template (template can be personal pages or emails). But in some special cases we need some more 'expensive' data. For example data from other applications get by web services. And even if there is no placeholder in the template that request the information it is loaded and put every time to the context hashmap.

So my question is , is there a alternative as template engine  (I also know 'Freemarker' and 'String template') that load needed content when it is necessary? Some kind of lazy loading template engine with less overhead

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You dont have to put everything / all values you might need in the context. Just put some kinde of object (or class if you want to use static methods) with getters in it to retrieve the values: `$myObject.getFirstname()`. for expesive stuff you can do the call when you need it `$myObject.getExpensiveData()`. Lazy loading should happen inside the method `getExpensiveData()`, so if a template doesnt need that stuff then it would not call that method and thus the loading wont happen.

Comment: Good suggestion. A sort of VelocityContextObject would suited best for this situation

Answer (score 3):

There is possibility to chain several contexts together,  say your inexpensive stuff goes to
standart context map and is served from there, and expensive ( like webservice calls )  is delegated toi your custom context.  This way you can provide lazy loading.

Velocity by itself has very little overhead.

Comment: Thank you. Good answer, but when are you going to add the 'expensive' context. Templates are created by the users, so we need then a template 'contains' functionality.

Comment: Context is created somwehere outside and provided to user. User creates cown context delegating to supercontext Template references something ,   default context ( supplied by user ) looks if it can provide reference, and delegates to super if not.

Comment: This is what VelocityTools 2 does for tools.  The custom context only creates them if they are requested by the template.  Chained contexts are awesome. :)

Answer (score 0):

Since you have asked this too, in FreeMarker the template context (called the data-model there) only have to implement the `TemplateHashModel` interface (or `java.util.Map`), so in your custom `get(String)` implementation you can defer resolving the variable value until it's first needed in the template.

Comment: Freemarker offers basically the same functionality - only problem  that I have with it that oroginal developers were (or still are) jerks who trolled  velocity mailing lists  beyond recognition.